# UINavigationBar tutorial with UITable?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have my UITable that works well, trying to get to another page when I select a row, havnt find toturial for this in C #. would be awsome if anyone knew of a good tutorial, or could explain how to do ..

Would like to understand how, in order to write the code just does not help ..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For static/hardcoded content in `UTableViews`, you should have a look at `Monotouch.Dialog`.

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Other then that: your question is kind of impossible to answer as it does not contain enough details.